# Slide Down Next UL from H3 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

```
<h3>Details<span class="dropdown">View</span></h3>
    <div id="sbc">
        <ul>
            <li><h2>Role: Supervisor</h2></li>
            <li>Manager Contact:</li>
            <li class="small">*location closed - please contact corporate office for further assistance</li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><h2>Responsibilities</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                <li>Assist customers with miscellaneous issues from AIV, AppStore, Kindle Tier 2</li>
                <li> - Fallback - Kindle Tier 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Trying to write jQuery to onClick slideDown the UL below the span.
Attempted multiple solutions, but all seem to fail.

This is my jQUery Code:

```
<script>
(function() {
    $('span.dropdown').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Racking my brain dry.... I'm not a complete noob (but apparently I am) and would love some help.

On Click
***Slide Down:
ul:after span

Toggle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$(this)
    .parent()        // Go to the parent h3 element of current span clicked
    .next('#sbc')    // Go to the next div element with id 'sbc'
    .children('ul')  // Go to its child ul element
    .slideToggle();  // and finally slide toggle
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question....
(yes, 12 seconds later)

```
<script>
(function() {
    $('span.dropdown').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().next('ul').slideToggle();
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Thanks for the help! I knew I was being an idiot and recording the DOM incorrectly :-P

Comment: I don't see how this can work, the parent `h3's` next element is the `div`, not `ul`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse to the parent first, get the next element, and then get the child `ul`:

```
$(this).parent().next().children('ul').slideToggle();
```

Since your `div` has an `id`, and an `id` must be unique, you could just do:

```
$('#sbc > ul').slideToggle();
```

Comment: In that case, either `ul` is not a direct descendent of `#sbc`, or you have multiple elements with the same `id` (`#sbc`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this  let me know

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', function() {
       $(this).parent().next().children('ul').slideToggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
$('span.dropdown').on('click', function() {
    $('ul').slideToggle();
   // alert('hi');
});
```